# Converting a Dask column into new Dask column of type datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dask

I have an unparsed column in a dask dataframe (df) that I am using pandas to convert to datetime and put into a new column in the dask dataframe. However it breaks as column assignment doesn't support type DatetimeIndex.

```
df['New Column'] = pd.to_datetime(np.array(df.index.values), format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```

Comment: I suggest you to check this discussion on [github](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3717) too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
# note df is a dask dataframe 
df['New Column'] = dd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```

Comment: How did I not try this! Thank you

Comment: I can't find this function on the latest Dask dataframe [page](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html)? Trying to convert `pd.to_datetime(firstdate, format='%Y-%m')` to its equivalent in Dask

Comment: It is [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.to_datetime) now in the docs for Dask 2.5.2.