# Dask Getting Error converting timestamp column to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, dask, unix-timestamp

I have a dask dataframe with thi structure:

```
Dask DataFrame Structure:
               timestamp      bid    offer     high      low mid_open   change change_pct market_delay market_state update_time
npartitions=76                                                                                                                 
                 float64  float64  float64  float64  float64  float64  float64    float64       object       object      object
                     
Dask Name: read-csv, 76 tasks
```

When I try to add a new columen called ds that uses the timestamp:

```
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')

kk['ds'] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(kk.timestamp), tz)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: Series.__float__ returned non-float (type function)
```

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584118/dask-dataframe-how-to-convert-column-to-to-datetime ...or this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51420042/10197418

Comment: Thanks @MrFuppes but its not really related. trying to first of all work out what the error is saying. Also cant use the to_datetime functionality of dask. Its design for string representations of time; we have Unix time and want to convert that

Answer (score 1):

Is `kk` a dask object?  If so then it is not a valid number, and so `float` won't know what to do with it.

I suspect that you may instead want to use the `.apply` method to apply a normal Python function across all of the rows in your series.