# converting Timestamp into proper format with DASK in python

Tags: python, pandas, dask

The following code is converting any kind of timestamp of dataframe into a given Format.

`pd.to_datetime(df_pd["timestamp"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X')`

How can I do this with "DASK"?
I used the below code but it did not work.

(df is dask dataframe)

```
a=dd.to_datetime(df["time:timestamp"],format='%Y-%m-%d %X')
a.compute()

Error-: ValueError: unconverted data remains: .304000+00:00
```

this is how timestamp look like-: `"2016-01-01 09:51:15.304000+00:00"` (This could be any kind of format)

Expected output -: `"2016-01-01 09:51:15"`

I found [Converting a Dask column into new Dask column of type datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420042/converting-a-dask-column-into-new-dask-column-of-type-datetime), but it is not working

Example with Pandas which works with any format-:

```
import pandas as pd
  

data = ['2016-01-01 09:51:15.304000+00:00','2016-01-01 09:51:15.304000+00:00','2016-01-01 09:51:15.304000+00:00','2016-01-01 09:51:15.304000+00:00']
data1 = ['2016-01-01 09:51:15','2016-01-01 09:51:15','2016-01-01 09:51:15','2016-01-01 09:51:15','2016-01-01 09:51:15']
data2 = ['2016-01-01','2016-01-01','2016-01-01','2016-01-01','2016-01-01']
  

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['t'])

df1['t']=pd.to_datetime(df1["t"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X')
```

Can someone tell me, how to do the same with "Dask"

*Here is my solution*

it could be done with following code-:
`dd.to_datetime(df["t"].compute()).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X')`

but now the problem is that i can't store this conversion in the existing dataframe like i did with pandas.

if i do `df["t"]=dd.to_datetime(df["t"].compute()).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X')`, it throws an error.

```
ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.
```

this [ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions error on dask dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030651/valueerror-not-all-divisions-are-known-cant-align-partitions-error-on-dask-da) does not workk

Answer (score 1):

As you already have the string in the almost correct format, maybe just with with the strings:

```
df_pd['timestamp'] = df_pd['timestamp'].str.replace(r'\..*', '', regex=True)
```

Alternatively, if you need to use `to_datetime`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df_pd["timestamp"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X')
```

Or:

```
pd.to_datetime(df_pd["timestamp"],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X')
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I think you did it with the "Pandas", But i want to do it with Dask. one solution is mentioned below, could you please take a look at answer and also the comment that i added.

Comment: I update the question as well, kindly take a look

Answer (score 1):

You can truncate the datetime:

```
# Solution 1
>>> dd.to_datetime(df['time:timestamp'].str[:19]).compute()
0   2016-01-01 09:51:15
dtype: datetime64[ns]


# Solution 2
>>> dd.to_datetime(df['time:timestamp'].str.split('.').str[0]).compute()
0   2016-01-01 09:51:15
dtype: datetime64[ns]


# Solution 3 (@mozway)
>>> dd.to_datetime(df['time:timestamp'].str.replace('\..*', '', regex=True)).compute()
0   2016-01-01 09:51:15
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But does it work for all kinds of timestamps? The one I mentioned with "pandas" can accept any kind of format and convert it into the "Expected timestamp" that I added there.

Comment: I update the question as well, kindly take a look

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it

````
df["time:timestamp"]=dd.to_datetime(df["time:timestamp"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X')

df.compute()```
````